# DLookup executing before being assigned to control source

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Below is my code:

```
Forms![OrderForm]![Sku].ControlSource = 
"=DLookUp(""[Sku]"",""OrderTable"",
""ItemNumber = '" & Forms![OrderForm]![ItemNumber] & "')"
```

I run the above code and the control source is now:

```
=DLookUp("[Sku]","OrderTable",
"ItemNumber = '1234-BA')
```

How do I change my code so I see the below in my control source:

```
=DLookUp("[Sku]","OrderTable",
"ItemNumber = '" & Forms![OrderForm]![ItemNumber] & "')
```

Comment: Have you tried *Me.ItemNumber*? (This is a completely untested suggestion, it's just how I would normally code that).  Assuming that doesn't work, can you tell us a bit more what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"=DLookUp(""Sku"",""OrderTable"",""ItemNumber='"" & "Forms![OrderForm]![ItemNumber]" & ""'"")"
```